# Can the boundary of a set be ignored, when integrating over it.

Tags: integration, manifolds

I'm confused whether the following statement is true:
Let $K$ be a compact, orientable manifold of dimension $n$ with boundary and $\omega$ be a smooth $n$-form on $K$. Say for example $K$ is the closed unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\omega$ is any $2$-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ restricted to $K$.
Is the following statement true?:
$$
 \int_{K} \omega = \int_{\overset{°}{K}} \omega
$$
, where $\overset{°}{K}$ is the interior of $K$.

I.e. can the boundary of a set be ignored when integrating over the set ?
I think it should be true, since the boundary should be a set of measure zero in $K$, but is there a flaw with this reasoning ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you define integrals on non-compact manifolds?

Comment: The title differs significantly from the body.  The integral over the boundary of a **manifold** is negligible.  The boundary of a **set** need not be measure zero.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613408/when-does-the-boundary-have-measure-zero

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.  The integral of $\omega$ is defined by adding together its integrals in coordinate charts with a partition of unity.  In each coordinate chart, the boundary $\partial K$ has measure $0$ (since the chart sends it to a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which has $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $0$), and so it does not affect the integral.