# Is the Haar measure of the boundary of an open subset of the $k$-torus zero?

Tags: measure-theory, manifolds, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

I have just recently started reading the basics of topological groups and Haar measures, and have become really curious about when the boundary of a non-empty open subset $U$ of a compact abelian group $G$, has zero Haar measure. Here and in the following, by "Haar measure", I will mean the normalized Haar measure of a compact abelian group.

After some searching, I found these posts ([When does the boundary have measure zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613408/when-does-the-boundary-have-measure-zero?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Conditions that ensure that the boundary of an open set has measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200573/conditions-that-ensure-that-the-boundary-of-an-open-set-has-measure-zero)) which give very general sufficient conditions for subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ to have boundaries of Lebesgue measure zero, however I couldn't find any analogues for Haar measures.

I would like to restrict $G$ to the $n$-torus $\mathbb T^n$, so here's my

**Semi-general question:** Consider the $n$-torus $\mathbb T^n = \mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$ which is a topological group, and a closed subgroup $H$ (which can be assumed to be connected if necessary). Consider the Haar measure $\mu_H$ on $H$ and an open set $U \subset \mathbb T^n$. What minimal additional conditions on $U$ might we need (if any) for the $H$-Haar measure of the boundary $\partial(U \cap H)$ of the open subset $U \cap H \subset H$ to be zero, that is to have $\mu_H(\partial (U \cap H)) = 0$?

If $H$ were $\mathbb T^n$ itself, then we know that $\mu_H$ is simply the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure and the question reduces to one already answered in the linked posts. If $H$ were an open subgroup, then (if I understand correctly) the Haar measure of $\mathbb T^n$ would also restrict to the normalized Haar measure of $H$, so that $\mu_H$ would just be the restriction of the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, and once again the question is answered. But of course, $\mathbb T^n$ being connected has no non-empty proper open subgroups, so the last statement doesn't really add anything in my context. So what about the general setting, namely when $H$ is a proper non-empty closed subgroup (again, assumed connected if necessary)?

If nothing can be said in the above setting (even with some minimal additional conditions), the specific $H$ and $U$ I would like to know about are the following: consider any real numbers $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ and any complex numbers $c_1, \cdots, c_n$. My $H$ is the closure of the subgroup $\{(e^{2 \pi i a_1 t}, \cdots, e^{2 \pi i a_n t}): t \in \mathbb R\} \subset \mathbb T^n$, and $U \subset \mathbb T^n$ is the set of all $(z_1, \cdots, z_n) \in \mathbb T^n$, for which the complex number $c_1z_1 + \cdots + c_n z_n$ has strictly positive real part. Can we say in this case that $\partial(U \cap H)$ has $H$-Haar measure zero?

**Note 1**: I do not know if this will be relevant, but in the above example, $U$ can be written as the intersection of $\mathbb T^n$ with the set $V := \{(z_1, \cdots, z_n) \in \mathbb C^n: \Re \sum_{j=1}^n c_j z_j > 0\} \subset \mathbb C^n$, so that $U \cap H = V \cap H$. Here, $V$ is both open and convex in $\mathbb C^n$, hence its boundary has zero Lebesgue measure.

**Note 2:** It might seem that the role of $U$ in my semi-general question is kind of superficial since we are really working with the open subset $U \cap H$ of $H$, but it is in line with my last example.

Comment: Do you know about Cantor sets of positive Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Wikipedia seems to give the example of a Smith–Volterra–Cantor set, but that is of course not convex. Also, could you please elaborate on what you have in mind? (In particular, how does it relate to minimal additional conditions I wish to find on open convex $U \subset \mathbb T^n$ for $U \cap H$ to have $H$-Haar measure zero?)

Comment: If you assume that your open subset is convex, then, of course, its boundary will have measure zero.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Is this true for the Haar measure on the closed subgroup $H$ too? Could you please give a reference (or the reasoning if it is short)? Sorry I am a newbie with topological groups ....

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Specifically, the last example I gave of $U$ and $H$ is what I am working with. Here $U \subset \mathbb T^n$ is open and convex, so that $U \cap H$ is still open in $H$ but $U \cap H$ need not be convex. Is it true that $\partial(U \cap H)$ has boundary of zero $H$-Haar measure?

Comment: Oops: silly error, I just realized that my $U$ is not convex as a subset of $\mathbb T^n$.

Comment: Every closed connected subgroup will be another torus, so it does not really matter, you can simply work with $R^n$ and Lebesgue measure.